# How to access the raw data produced by GMSH python API without other python packages?

Tags: python, gmsh

I want to access all the mesh information directly. I don't want to save the created mesh using a <filename.msh> file. How is it possible? Also I don't want to use the meshio or pygmsh or anyother package.

EDIT:
I used the following lines and obtained the tetrahedrons from the msh file. Still I needed to write it. I need to do it without writing it externally.

```
    a,b = gmsh.model.mesh.getElementsByType(4, -1)
    b.reshape(-1,4)
```

Also I want the output in the following format. That is the complete line in the msh file as below:

```
147 4 2 0 1 26 13 8 16
```

But I get only

```
26 13 8 16
```